# Create a series of new columns with (d)plyr

Tags: r, data.table, plyr, dplyr

Say for example I have a data frame with a column `a` and I want to create columns `a^i` for several values of `i`.

```
> dat <- data.frame(a=1:5)
> dat
    a
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
```

As an example, the output I want for `i=2:5`:

```
  a power_2 power_3 power_4 power_5
1 1       1       1       1       1
2 2       4       8      16      32
3 3       9      27      81     243
4 4      16      64     256    1024
5 5      25     125     625    3125
```

Currently I get this output with `data.table` as follows:

```
DT <- data.table(dat)
exponents <- 2:5
DT[, paste0("power_",exponents):=lapply(exponents, function(p) a^p)]
```

How to do with `plyr`/`dplyr` ? Of course I could do as below by typing `power_i=a^i` for each `i` but this is not what I want.

```
mutate(dat, power_2=a^2, power_3=a^3, ...)
```

### Conclusion after answers

Several answers have been proposed, and have been compared by @docendo discimus. I'm just adding the comparison with `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(2015)
dat <- data.frame(a = sample(1000))
i <- 2:5
n <- c(names(dat), paste0("power_", i))
DT <-  data.table(dat)

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  data.table = DT[, paste0("power_",i):=lapply(i, function(k) a^k)],
  Henrik = dat %>% do(data.frame(., outer(.$a, i, `^`))) %>% setNames(n),
  dd.do = dat %>% do(data.frame(., sapply(i, function(x) .$a^x))) %>% setNames(n),
  dd.bc = dat %>% bind_cols(as.data.frame(lapply(i, function(x) .$a^x))) %>% setNames(n),
  times = 30,
  unit = "relative"
)
Unit: relative
       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
 data.table  1.022945  1.039674  1.108558  1.026319  1.083644  2.370180    30  a 
     Henrik  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000    30  a 
      dd.do  1.149195  1.160735  1.167672  1.158141  1.150280  1.268279    30  a 
      dd.bc 14.350034 13.982658 13.737964 13.632361 13.606221 15.866711    30   b
```

**Updated benchmark** with two `base` solutions, Henrik2 and josh (from his comment), which are fastest:

```
set.seed(2015)
dat <- data.frame(a = sample(1000))

microbenchmark(
  data.table = DT[, paste0("power_",i):=lapply(i, function(k) a^k)],
  Henrik = dat %>% do(data.frame(., outer(.$a, i, `^`))) %>% setNames(n),
  Henrik2 = cbind(dat, outer(dat$a, setNames(i, paste0("power_", i)),  `^`)),
  dd.do = dat %>% do(data.frame(., sapply(i, function(x) .$a^x))) %>% setNames(n),
  dd.bc = dat %>% bind_cols(as.data.frame(lapply(i, function(x) .$a^x))) %>% setNames(n),
  josh = data.frame(dat, setNames(lapply(2:5, function(X) dat$a^X), paste0("power_", 2:5))),
  times = 30,
  unit = "relative"
)

# Unit: relative
#       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval  cld
# data.table  1.991613  2.029778  1.982169  1.990417  1.946677  1.694030    30  bc 
#     Henrik  2.026345  2.017179  1.996419  2.003189  2.030176  1.733583    30  bc 
#    Henrik2  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000    30 a   
#      dd.do  2.356886  2.375713  2.322452  2.348053  2.304826  2.101494    30   c 
#      dd.bc 37.445491 36.081298 34.791638 34.783854 34.787655 27.832116    30    d
#       josh  1.725750  1.699887  1.641290  1.625331  1.637823  1.330598    30  b
```

Comment: Interesting that in this case, good old base R is fastest with `data.frame(dat, setNames(lapply(2:5, function(X) dat$a^X), paste0("power_", 2:5)))` clocking in as ~17% faster than method `Henrik`.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Please also see my updated answer with a non-`do` (`base`) version which is twice as fast as my `do` code.

Comment: @Henrik -- Very nice. Looks like `outer` is faster than `lapply`, at least in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an option using `do`:

```
i <- 2:5
n <- c(names(dat), paste0("power_", i))
dat %>% do(data.frame(., sapply(i, function(x) .$a^x))) %>% setNames(n)
#  a power_2 power_3 power_4 power_5
#1 1       1       1       1       1
#2 2       4       8      16      32
#3 3       9      27      81     243
#4 4      16      64     256    1024
#5 5      25     125     625    3125
```

Another option, using `bind_cols`:

```
dat %>% bind_cols(as.data.frame(lapply(i, function(x) .$a^x))) %>% setNames(n)
#  a power_2 power_3 power_4 power_5
#1 1       1       1       1       1
#2 2       4       8      16      32
#3 3       9      27      81     243
#4 4      16      64     256    1024
#5 5      25     125     625    3125
```

---

Edit after comment:

The solution by @Henrik is faster than mine:

```
set.seed(2015)
dat <- data.frame(a = sample(1000))
i <- 2:5
n <- c(names(dat), paste0("power_", i))

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  Henrik = dat %>% do(data.frame(., outer(.$a, i, `^`))) %>% setNames(n),
  dd.do = dat %>% do(data.frame(., sapply(i, function(x) .$a^x))) %>% setNames(n),
  dd.bc = dat %>% bind_cols(as.data.frame(lapply(i, function(x) .$a^x))) %>% setNames(n),
  times = 30,
  unit = "relative"
  )
Unit: relative
   expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
 Henrik  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000    30
  dd.do  1.138506  1.179104  1.173298  1.149581  2.660237    30
  dd.bc 18.862923 18.702178 18.058984 17.537727 16.426538    30
```

Comment: I think this is actually the perfect use-case for `do`.

Comment: The solution using `do` looks like the one given by @Henrik. It would be nice to know which one is the more efficient.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, I added a comparison

Comment: Sad you have not compared with the `data.table` solution ;)

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, I'm expecting data.table to be faster than these dplyr::do solutions, but didn't benchmark them since you were asking for the difference between Henrik's and mine..

Comment: Ok, I will do it and include it in my OP. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

One possibility is to use `outer` in `do`, and then set the names with `setNames`

```
i <- 2:5
dat %>%
  do(data.frame(., outer(.$a, i, `^`))) %>%
  setNames(., c("a", paste0("power_", i)))

#   a power_2 power_3 power_4 power_5
# 1 1       1       1       1       1
# 2 2       4       8      16      32
# 3 3       9      27      81     243
# 4 4      16      64     256    1024
# 5 5      25     125     625    3125
```

If you name the 'power vector' "i" first, you can call `cbind` instead of `do` and `data.frame`, and I see no immediate need for `dplyr` functions in this particular case.

```
cbind(dat, outer(dat$a, setNames(i, paste0("power_", i)),  `^`))
#   a power_2 power_3 power_4 power_5
# 1 1       1       1       1       1
# 2 2       4       8      16      32
# 3 3       9      27      81     243
# 4 4      16      64     256    1024
# 5 5      25     125     625    3125
```

The `base`, non-`do` code is faster for your larger sample data. I also added the `base` solution by @Josh O'Brien.

```
set.seed(2015)
dat <- data.frame(a = sample(1000))

microbenchmark(
  data.table = DT[, paste0("power_",i):=lapply(i, function(k) a^k)],
  Henrik = dat %>% do(data.frame(., outer(.$a, i, `^`))) %>% setNames(n),
  Henrik2 = cbind(dat, outer(dat$a, setNames(i, paste0("power_", i)),  `^`)),
  dd.do = dat %>% do(data.frame(., sapply(i, function(x) .$a^x))) %>% setNames(n),
  dd.bc = dat %>% bind_cols(as.data.frame(lapply(i, function(x) .$a^x))) %>% setNames(n),
  josh = data.frame(dat, setNames(lapply(2:5, function(X) dat$a^X), paste0("power_", 2:5))),
  times = 30,
  unit = "relative"
)

# Unit: relative
#       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval  cld
# data.table  1.991613  2.029778  1.982169  1.990417  1.946677  1.694030    30  bc 
#     Henrik  2.026345  2.017179  1.996419  2.003189  2.030176  1.733583    30  bc 
#    Henrik2  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000    30 a   
#      dd.do  2.356886  2.375713  2.322452  2.348053  2.304826  2.101494    30   c 
#      dd.bc 37.445491 36.081298 34.791638 34.783854 34.787655 27.832116    30    d
#       josh  1.725750  1.699887  1.641290  1.625331  1.637823  1.330598    30  b
```

Comment: @Stèphane Laurent, I have updated my answer with a 'non-`do`' solution, which probably is faster.

Comment: Henrik, FWIW, there was an unnecessary copy that was happening in data.table on updating by reference, that was fixed in 1.9.5. So you may want to test against that. Also interesting would be to test with `set()`.

Comment: @Arun, Thanks for your comment. I don't have 1.9.5 right now, so feel free to run the benchmark and edit my answer (or the benchmark which I added to the question). Cheers.

Comment: You deserve the check mark for the best answer here. I was expecting the OP to accept yours when writing in my initial benchmark that your answer is faster than mine.

Answer (score 1):

May be this also helps

```
nm1 <- paste('power', 2:5, sep="_")
lst <- setNames(as.list(2:5), nm1)
dat1 <- setNames(as.data.frame(replicate(4, 1:5)),c('a', nm1) )
mutate_each_(dat1, funs(.^lst$.), nm1)
#    a power_2 power_3 power_4 power_5
#1 1       1       1       1       1
#2 2       4       8      16      32
#3 3       9      27      81     243
#4 4      16      64     256    1024
#5 5      25     125     625    3125
```